# Google Calendar looks broken in Chromium and Firefox

Tags: chromium, html5

When I open up google calendar in Chromium or Firefox it looks kinda broken and not as it looks on my desktop PC

[image]

I could not find any useful help on the Interwebs. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Looks like a mobile version to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the best way, but use the url from a desktop PC and type into your chromium browser (yours is showing the mobile version) and bookmark it, until theres a better answer.